# Adding text Javascript progressbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I would like to add a description text to my progress bar. This description text shoud appear at the left top of the bar. The best way to do it is by modifying my Javascript. It should be very easy to do but i don't have a lot of knowledge in js and I don't know how to do it.

Here is the code :

HTML :

```
<div id="cont"></div>
```

CSS :

```
#cont {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
```

JS :

```
var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(cont, {
    strokeWidth: 4,
    easing: 'easeInOut',
    duration: 1400,
    color: '#ed1100',
    trailColor: '#eee',
    trailWidth: 1,
    svgStyle: {width: '100%', height: '100%'},
    text: {
      style: {
        // Text color.
        // Default: same as stroke color (options.color)
        color: '#999',
        position: 'absolute',
        right: '0',
        top: '30px',
        padding: 0,
        margin: 0,
        transform: null
      },
      autoStyleContainer: false
    },
    from: {color: '#ed1100'},
    to: {color: '#ED6A5A'},
    step: (state, bar) => {
      bar.setText(Math.round(bar.value() * 100) + ' %');
    }
  });

  bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```

It also uses another JS you can find here : http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/

Code in use :
https://jsfiddle.net/kimmobrunfeldt/k5v2d0rr/

Can someone help me to add this description text ?

Comment: How do you want to add the text? As a attribute in the html, or as a variable in Javascript?

Comment: A variable in Javascript would be nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this? 
https://jsfiddle.net/k5v2d0rr/1996/

You could just extend the "bar" object with your own function:

```
bar.addText = function(text) {
    jQuery(this._container).append("<label>" + text + "</label>");
}
```

You then call your function after loading your bar.

```
bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
bar.addText("Hi");
```

Note: for simplicity I've added jQuery for DOM manipulation.

Comment: Yes, exactly like this :). Thanks for your help :).

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark my answer as the valid solution and upvote.